# How to get header value in UploadStringCompletedEventHandler method ASP.NET (Web API Service using HttpClient)

Tags: web-services, webclient, asp.net-web-api2

In My Windows Phone 8 App, I create `WebClient` object and initiate the with `UploadStringAsync.` and Create `webClientLogin.UploadStringCompleted` using `UploadStringCompletedEventHandler.`

```
WebClient webClientLogin = new WebClient();
webClientLogin.Headers["content-type"] = "application/json";             
webClientLogin.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClientUploadStringCompleted);
webClientLogin.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(URL + "LogIn"), "POST", stockiestData);
```

Here stockiestData is Encoded Using `Encoding.UTF8`

I Get response as well.

```
private void webClientUploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var logindetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogResponse>(e.Result);
}
```

But I need to get the Header in this above method (webClientUploadStringCompleted). 
I send the header like follows `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Msg","Checked");`
This response created in `WebApi`
How to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to get header values using sender Object in the following method.

```
private void webClientUploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

We have to cast this object as WebClient. 
Following method shows how to send in WebApi

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("LogIn")]
    public dynamic LogIn(List<Student> Student, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (Student!= null) 
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Msg", "Resived");  
        }
```

Following code shows you how to get header value from Windows phone 8

```
private void webClientUploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
WebClient web = (WebClient)sender;
WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = (WebHeaderCollection)web.ResponseHeaders;
var v = web.ResponseHeaders["Msg"];
}
```